# Any way to see all my current total stats (regen, resistance, armor rating, etc) in Skyrim?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

When having various gear giving various kinds of stat boosts, resistances, regen, etc, is there a way to see a complete picture of what they currently are? For example to see my total fire or magic resistance?

Comment: go to the magic screen and the go to the bottom for active effects, all of your perks and curses will show there including ones from your equipment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately no way to list all values at once (as far as I've found), but discovered you can get the current total value of something in the console using [Actor Values](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Console_Commands_(Skyrim)/ActorValues), for example:

```
player.getav damageresist
player.getav magicresist
```

Answer (score 1):

I recommend to use this mod

http://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/61124/?

It shows complete info about yout current char.
It needs SkyUi and SKSE

Comment: Good tip, but unfortunately neither SKSE or SkuUI is available yet for Skyrim SE 

Comment: @Svish, sadly :(

Answer (score 0):

Nope.

If you look at "Active Effects" under the magic menu, you can manually figure it out.

Answer (score -1):

If you go to the screen where it gives you options for map, items, level up, etc click the top one and see skills. That will show you your levels for what you said.

Comment: the question is asking about stat boosts, not skills